# Remove all the commits/merges done from another branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch

How do I remove all the merges made to a branch. And I'm not talking about reverting a single merge.

To get more into detail. I was working on two seperate branches, very closely related. Branch "Tools" and branch "feature". Branch "feature" relied on a specific tool from branch "tool". So through out the life span of the project I merged updates from "tools" branch into "feature" branch. (**Never the other way around**)

As the feature is near it's development end, we decided to move forward and make "feature" a stand-alone to go into an upcoming release. "Tools" is still far from being released so we carried over some code for "feature" to work without "tools". But "Tools" is still in "Feature". How would I remove all the commits or merges made from branch "Tools"?

I was thinking git-rebase -i, but there is way too many commits for me to go through to remove without enough detail on what was changed. Is there another way to do this?

```
--->Master--\  #Feature Branch Created from Master, and Master merged into Tools.
             \
--->--->Tools \---------\------\------\-------\---->--------->
                         \      \      \       \
        Feature |---------\------\------\-------\--->[Finished]
```

Is there a way to do this like so where B=Feature-Branch and A=Tools-Branch
git rebase (B-A) 
Any help would be apprciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does removing the merge commits leave the other commits in a 'functional' enough state for you?  Prior to removing the dependency on tools I mean.  If 'yes', then i think you could just use `git rebase` which will by default throw out all the merges for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this in two stages:

- on branch master, `git cherry-pick <list of commits in tools that you actually need>`
- `git rebase --onto master tools feature` (this will delete all remaining `tools` commits from branch `feature`, and instead use the version on `master`)

Chances are you'll mess up a few times guessing what's really need, so be very familiar with `git reflog` and the `--abort` flag to most branch-management commands.

Comment: Took a while to do the rebase, but I got it to where I needed the branch to be. :) thanks!